# The problem of converting python list to c#List<int>

Tags: python, c#

I want to create simple project which I've got simple python list like this:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Also I have C# dynamic library. In the library I need to create a function which will allow to get this python list. Code should look like this.

```
public void getPythonList(List<int> list)
```

I have created in python function to call c# library via `import clr`

When I start the program, my IDE shows this error:
`Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'list' value cannot be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.String]`

The problem is I don't know what type of data is getting in the C# library, when I send this python list.

My question is how this community convert python list to c# list?

Comment: Seems, you have created an array of integers in python instead of `List<int>`. Change the declaration of your C# method to accept array ;) Or... Create a list by using list constructor: `list = list((1,2,3,4,5))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easier way but you can always use the C# types.

```
clr.AddReference('System.Collections')
from System.Collections.Generic import List

my_list = List[int]()
my_list.Add(1)

foo = MyLibraryClass()
bar = foo.getPythonList(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you will have to create a binding library which will have the type definition of all the properties and methods.

Comment: You are suggesting what to do but you don't provide a written solution. This should be a comment :)

Comment: You are right. But, I am new and I don't have enough reputation to comment on other's posts.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to using strings. How can one create a list of string in python

```
clr.AddReference('System.Collections')
from System.Collections.Generic import List

my_list = List[int]()
my_list.Add(1)

foo = MyLibraryClass()
bar = foo.getPythonList(my_list)
```